# How to specify variable location in physical memory?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

gcc allows to control a section where a variable is placed to using the section attribute:

```
struct duart a __attribute__ ((section ("DUART_A"))) = { 0 };
```

Is there a way to specify an exact location of this section in physical memory in my C-code?  I assume no virtual memory present, or, alternatively, virtual address is directly translated into physical address.

I know i can handle it through a script I pass to the linker, but it would be better if I could to specify it directly in my (autogenerated) C.

Comment: your example is not 'physical memory'.  You cannot specify the physical location of a var unless you are using some OS that doesn't use virtual memory. Maybe some you can do that in some embedded system.

Comment: You're right. My assumption was no virtual memory.

Comment: **Why** would it be "better" to not use the linker for this? That's what the linker is **for**!

Comment: @detly It's my specific case and is related to the way the code is organised. We have auto-generated C code where we need to put some variables at certain physical locations. The exact physical location varies and comes from outside (eg, config file)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect of having the variable at some physical address by using a macro, for example:

```
#define a (*(volatile struct duart *)0xdeadbeef)
```

This doesn't use the linker; it doesn't declare any variables so you won't see `a` in the object file. But i guess you don't need this.

Note `volatile` keyword, which is always needed when using memory-mapped hardware. It will often work without `volatile`, but sometimes it won't, and debugging such failures is hard - so don't forget that `volatile` keyword!

Usage:

```
// I assume the duart structure has fields write_buf and read_buf of type uint8_t
a.write_buf = 0x55; // write data to DUART
a.write_buf = 0xaa; // write more data to DUART
uint8_t byte1 = a.read_buf; // read data from DUART
uint8_t byte2 = a.read_buf; // read more data from DUART
```

Comment: And what if the system uses virtual memory?

Comment: @Bo Persson Then, i don't know.

Comment: @Bo-Persson I assumed no virtual memory. I corrected my question

Comment: Unfortunately such a definition (with a cast) cannot be used as a template parameter :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to define a pointer to your structure and initialize it with the correct value, so you don't need special linker options. Of course, the trick works only if you don't need any speciel link-time feature.

Bye!